# How do I make a button that executes code in a asp.net web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am trying to make a button on the webpage that executes some code and I can't get the button to execute anything

The code in the .cshtml page:

```
<div>
<input type="button" value="Check for new Scenarios" onclick="NewScenario_Click" />
</div>
```

The code in the .cshtml.cs page:

```
void NewScenario_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");

        }
```

Comment: HTML doesn't have server-side click events.  Instead, use AJAX or a form. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#write-a-basic-form

Comment: How would I go about using a form?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#write-a-basic-form

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to setup either a javascript listener (or Jquery or something else clientside) that calls an AJAX request to route to server side code.
 something like this might work:

Change the input to:

```
<div>
<input type="button" id="newScenario" value="Check for new Scenarios" onclick="NewScenario_Click"/>
</div>
```

And then make a new javascript script that does something similar to the following (I'm using Jquery on this BTW)

```
var button = $('#newScenario');
button.on('Click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'PATH_TO_SERVER',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            alert("button pressed!");
        },
        error: function(request, error){
            alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
});
```